# ActiveRecord get all + associated details

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I am trying to retrieve a list of all tasks, where each task has a developer and reviewer. I am able to retrieve the list but it contains developer_id and reviewer_id. How do I retrieve a list containing developer name and retriever name?

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Unread_Object < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end

class Developer < Person
  has_many :tasks 
end
class Reviewer < Person
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :unread_objects
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :developer
  belongs_to :reviewer
  has_many :documents
  after_save :add_task_to_unread_objects

  protected
    def add_task_to_unread_objects
      Person.find_each do |person|
        Unread_Object.create(
                              :person_id => person.id,
                              :internal_object_id => self.internal_object_id,
                              :unread_cause => 'Create')
      end
    end
end
```

Things I have tried.

```
get '/taskslist' do
  #Task.includes([:developer, :reviewer]).all.to_json
  #Task.joins(:developer,:reviewer).select("tasks.*, people.*").to_json #works somewhat but only shows one name
  #Task.includes(:reviewer.name,:developer.name).all.to_json #"undefined method `name' for :reviewer:Symbol"
  #Task.find(:all, :include => {:people => :name}).to_json #Couldn't find all Tasks with 'id': (all, {:include=>{:people=>:name}}) 
end
```

I hope to get Tasks json with nested json for developer, reviewer and other objects.
This question is follow up of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261253/derived-activerecord-ruby-class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching found `as_json(include: <association>)`
So this works

```
Task.includes(:developer,:reviewer).all.as_json(include: [:developer,:reviewer]).to_json
```

But other alternatives need to be seen.